# dedicated handler object for a jsf Composite Component

Tags: jsf, cdi, composite-component

I want to add many instances of a composite component to one jsf view. Each composite component should have a dedicated/not shared cdi (handler) bean. If i make the handler bean viewscoped/request scoped every composite component on the view would call to same instance. Is there an easy solution to this problem?

I use jsf 2.2 with primefaces on wildfly 10 server.

Comment: Are you sure you need a dedicated/not shared cdi (handler) bean or do you need a composite component with a dedicated backing bean (http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html) ? A dedicated 'handler' bean per component instance is sort of not the best design and in many cases not needed (you can e.g. detect which component initiated a request in another way). So might be running into an http://xyproblem.info here.

Comment: I am sorry i do not really understand the difference between your two points. The composite component would be complex and i dont want one handler to manage a lot of them. Sure i could pass some parameter to one handler to determine the cc instances but why should i do that myself if the cointainer could do that by creating a dedicated handler for each cc.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have a composite component with input fields, and each input should be handled by a dedicated handler instance.

Comment: No i didnt. I made one Handler and needed to pass an identifier from each composite component to the handler.